# How to use regex in python to catch patterns like keyword1 [arbitrary characters with a max length of 5] keyword2

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

How can I use re package to recognize a pattern as

```
keyword1 [arbitrary characters with a max length of 5] keyword2
```

For example, `keyword1 abc keyword2` is valid, `keyword1 a . keyword2` is also valid
but `keyword1 1234abd keyword2` is not valid

Thank you

Comment: Are the spaces after `keyword1` and before `keyword2` included in the 5 character limit? e.g. is `keyword1 abcd keyword2` valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r"(?:keyword1).{5}(?:keyword2)
```

Checked this on https://regex101.com/